# Dialog won't unmount when dismissed while mobile keyboard is open

Tags: reactjs, dialog, tailwind-css, headless-ui

I'm using React, TailwindCSS, and HeadlessUI by TailwindLabs.

I'm trying to make a dialog using the Headless UI Dialog component and the Transition component so that the dialog looks like this on desktop:
[image]

And like this on mobile:
[image]

However, I found out that the dialog component doesn't unmount in this specific scenario that is **VERY** easy to trigger

1. User is on mobile
2. User opens the dialog
3. User focuses the textbox and the mobile keyboard is visible
4. User then clicks the backdrop behind the dialog, dismissing the dialog. The user is performing this while the mobile keyboard is still active
5. Dialog dismisses and transitions out of view. Though the component doesn't unmount and blocks any interaction on any components underneath (buttons, text inputs, etc).

Video demonstration:
https://youtube.com/shorts/Qhr1_azemaM?feature=share

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/convoy-reproduction-environment-bjs4vr?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A64%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A11%2C%22startColumn%22%3A7%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A11%7D%5D&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522cl9zkf3e9000alqiphi669wk8%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252Felements%252FModal.tsx%2522%252C%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.tsx%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522sidekickItems%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clan6rf4001ke376i80a287gn%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clan6re0c01g3376ioybsxh1c%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Atrue%257D%255D%257D)

The actual result I want is when the user dismisses while the virtual keyboard is open, the dialog should transition out of view and unmount so that underlying elements can be interacted with.

Comment: Does this happen only on mobile?

Comment: @BadalSaibo Yes! This happens just on mobile. Specifically when the mobile keyboard is open. You can reproduce this with the video/instructions/reproduction link. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a valid bug and I noticed it happens only when you do it instantly.
If you type something and wait for sometime and close the dialog it doesn't happens.

To get around I have used a `setTimeout` so there's a delay while setting the `setOpen` to `false`

```
  const handleClose = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setOpen(false);
    }, 0);
  };
```

```
 <Modal     
    open={open}     
    onClose={handleClose}
    title="Create a Backup"
    description="Creating a backup will take a copy of your server files. This can take a while depending on the size of your server."
 >
...
</Modal>
```

Comment: I see. This is a really weird bug! Well, thank you for your insight! I appreciate it a lot. I have been pulling at my hair trying to see if it was a CSS bug and even tried editing the Headless UI package in a fork.